# Xamarin, Overriding the Focus Change in a custom renderer stops focus events from occurring

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a custom entry field that prevents the soft keyboard from appearing when the entry field get focus. However this prevents the normal focus/unfocus events from occurring.  Here is the code for the Android renderer

```
Control.FocusChange += (sender, eh) =>
{
    new Handler().Post(delegate
    {
     if (eh.HasFocus)
         if (Control != null)
         {
              var imm =
                (InputMethodManager)Control.Context.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.InputMethodService);
                    imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(Control.WindowToken, 0);
          }
      });
      };
```

Is this a bug in Xamarin or is there a way to have the focus and unfocus events fire.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when trying to hide an already opened soft keyboard when focusing a `DatePicker` or `TimePicker`. (In some Android phones the soft keyboard stayed on top of the date/time picker dialogs).

When using `Control.FocusChange` event handler, the default behaviour of opening the picker dialogs was not being triggered.

**Solution:**
After hiding the keyboard, call the `Focus()` method on the element to trigger the normal focus events and default behaviour.

Here is my Android DatePicker renderer code:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<DatePicker> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    if (Control == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    Control.ShowSoftInputOnFocus = false;
    Control.FocusChange += (sender, args) => HideSoftKeyboard(e.NewElement, args);
}

private void HideSoftKeyboard(DatePicker e, FocusChangeEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.HasFocus)
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            var inputMethodManager = Context.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService) as InputMethodManager;
            inputMethodManager?.HideSoftInputFromWindow(Control.WindowToken, HideSoftInputFlags.None);
            e?.Focus();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, I think you're right to try to dismiss the keyboard in UI thread, I'm not sure that happens with `new Handler().Post()` here, but you can use `BeginInvokeOnMainThread` to force the code run on UI thread:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);
    if (Control != null)
    {
        Control.FocusChange += (sender, eh) =>
        {
            if (eh.HasFocus)
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    var imm = (InputMethodManager)Control.Context.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
                    imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(Control.WindowToken, HideSoftInputFlags.None);
                });
            }
        };
    }
}
```

This code works by my side and the `FocusChange` event can be fired normally.